# How to fetch eBay token using PHP?

Tags: php, token, secret-key

I'm trying to generate token for my application.
My request is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FetchTokenRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>EBAYTOKEN</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <SecretID>??</SecretID>
    <SessionID>SeSSID</SessionID>
    <ErrorLanguage> string </ErrorLanguage>
    <MessageID> string </MessageID>
    <Version>893</Version>
    <WarningLevel>Low</WarningLevel>
</FetchTokenRequest>
```

And I get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FetchTokenResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2014-10-14T13:39:28.897Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Failure</Ack>
    <CorrelationID> string </CorrelationID>

    <Errors>
        <ShortMessage>The end user has not completed Auth &amp; Auth sign in flow.</ShortMessage>
        <LongMessage>The end user has not completed Auth &amp; Auth sign in flow.</LongMessage>
        <ErrorCode>21916017</ErrorCode>
        <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
        <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
    </Errors>
    <Version>893</Version>
    <Build>E893_CORE_API_17097905_R1</Build>
</FetchTokenResponse>
```

I have the session id, and token, but I'm not sure of my secret id. How can I fix this problem? Is it related to the `secret ID`? Where can I find the secretID from ebay?

Comment: have you tried with just the sessionID?

Comment: no , i can work just with session id , but i still have this problem :The end user has not completed Auth &amp; Auth sign in flow !!!!!!  :(

Answer (score 1):

> **SecretID**:
>   A value associated with the token retrieval request. SecretID is defined by the application, and is passed in the redirect URL to the eBay sign-in page. eBay recommends using a UUID for the secret ID value. You must also set Username (part of the RequesterCredentials) for the particular user of interest. **SecretID and Username are not required if SessionID is present**.

The above quote is from this page; [Ebay Developer Zone - FetchToken.html](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/FetchToken.html)